# Firemonkey dragging image not showing on screen

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

The following first image is taken from a Virtual Machine and second is taken from a real pc. Why don't I see the dragging image on the real PC?

**Virtual Machine**

[image]

**Real PC**

[image]

Comment: Please use an image sharing site that allows more than 1 download per 30 minutes!!!

Comment: ok I changed the url of the images.

Comment: One machine is themed XP. The other is Windows Classic, or Windows 2000. Please supply details.

Comment: You are right. I would like to appear in both. How can I do?

Comment: Please supply full OS details. Of both machines. Include the appearance preferences, themed or not.

Comment: first (vm) is Windows Xp Service pack 2 32 bit and themed. second (rm) is Windows 7 64 bit, Windows clasic.

Comment: Try wwitching the real PC to themed. You can see that FireMonkey does not respect Windows Classic by the way it draws the button. I don't think FireMonkey really cares about what visuals you the user prefer.

Comment: yes, I did. Image shows when dragging on the Real PC.

Comment: OK, looks like it's nothing to do with VM or real PC, and all to do with Windows Classic vs themed. I suggest you submit a QC report describing what you have found.